# Sequelize get own attributes only, ignore included instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

What I'm looking for is an instance method in [`Model`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html) that will return only the attributes of that model & exclude instances of any included model.

eg: Imagine I have 2 models, with a `hasMany` ( or any ) association:

```
Post {
  id,
  content,
  user_id
}

User: {
  id,
  name,
}
```

and I have:

```
const userWithPosts = await User.findOne({
  where: { id: 33 },
  include: [{
    model: Post,
    as: 'posts'
  }]
});
console.log(userWithPosts)
/*
  {
    id: 33,
    name: 'John Doe',
    posts: [
      Post {
        id: 1,
        content: '..',
        user_id: 33
      },
      Post {
        id: 2,
        content: '...',
        user_id: 33
      }
    ]
  }
*/
```

I'm looking for a method, say `getOwnAttributes` or something like that which does:

```
userWithPosts.getOwnAttributes()
/*
{
  id: 33,
  name: 'John Doe',
}
*/
```

I've looked into couple of things:

```
userWithPosts.get({ raw: true })
userWithPosts.get({ plain: true })
userWithPosts.toJSON()
```

All of the above returns included instances as well.
Any existing method or workaround that can do this?

**EDIT:** I'm not talking about doing it at query time, but getting the value from already queried instance. Currently my work-around for this is:

```
const payload = _.pick(userWithPosts.toJSON(), [
  ...Object.keys(User.rawAttributes),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the code below to exclude attributes of `Post` table.

```
const userWithPosts = await User.findOne({
  where: { id: 33 },
  include: [{
    model: Post,
    as: 'posts',
    attributes: []
  }]
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, that helps. But I was looking for a method which can be run on the model instance, after querying.